# bubble sort already sorted list

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I want to stop my bubble sort function from running if it is passed a list that is already ordered (or already ordered half way through being bubble sorted)

I have defined my bubble sort function as

```
def swap(values,i,j):
    values[i],values[j]=values[j],values[i]

def bubble(values):
    for i in range (len(values)-1):
        if values[i]>values[i+1]:
            swap(values,i,i+1)

def bubble_sort(values):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        count += 1
        bubble(values)
    return count
```

Here I'm counting the number of times I call the bubble function to see how many times a swap is performed. I want to alter the code so that if it is given a list that is already sorted, the `bubble_sort()` function will stop calling the `bubble()` function.

I know I will have to use a boolean in the bubble function that returns if any values were swapped but I'm not sure on how to actually implement it.

Answer (score 2):

as Jorge show in answer but don't explain (as off jet) put a Boolean variable in bubble that default to True or False, whatever you choose, change its value to oposite if you do a swap and return that variable at the end, if the value you get from bubble is your default value, that means that your list is ordered otherwise is not and you must continue to call that function. Then you can change the main function to a while loop like this

```
def bubble(values):
    "return true if a swap was made, false otherwise" 
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        if values[i]>values[i+1]:
            swap(values,i,i+1)
            flag = True
    return flag

def bubble_sort(values):
    count = 0 
    while bubble(values): # while there is a swap...
        count += 1
    return count
```

test

```
>>> test=[1,9,4,7,2,8,10,5,6,3]
>>> bubble_sort(test)
7
>>> test
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> bubble_sort(test)
0
>>> test
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

Comment: though this while implementation will ignore the already sorted part on the right, still trying to swap all the way to last element on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap(values,i,j):
    values[i],values[j]=values[j],values[i]

def bubble(values):
    flag = False
    for i in range (len(values)-1):
        if values[i]>values[i+1]:
            flag = True
            swap(values,i,i+1)
    return flag

def bubble_sort(values):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        count += 1
        if(not bubble(values))
            break
    return count
```

Comment: you have `true/false` instead of `True/False` I tried to make edit but I have to change at least 6 characters

Comment: Could you at least try to answer the question?